# Deploying Gradle project on Heroku

Tags: java, gradle, heroku

The problem is when I have the project deployed on Heroku after running

```
heroku local web
```

it would show the following

```
C:\Users\Richer\OneDrive\Project>heroku local web
5:22:24 PM web.1 |  Error: Could not find or load main class $JAVA_OPTS
[DONE] Killing all processes with signal  SIGINT
5:22:25 PM web.1 Exited with exit code null
```

and if I run

```
heroku ps
```

the shell will show

```
C:\Users\Richer\OneDrive\Project>heroku ps
Free dyno hours quota remaining this month: 549h 21m (99%)
Free dyno usage for this app: 0h 0m (0%)
For more information on dyno sleeping and how to upgrade, see:https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-sleeping

=== web (Free): java -Dserver.port=$PORT $JAVA_OPTS -jar build/libs/*.jar (1)
web.1: crashed 2018/10/12 17:22:22 +0300 (~ 14m ago)
```

my Procfile looks like this

```
web: java -Dserver.port=$PORT $JAVA_OPTS -jar build/libs/*.jar
```

If it helps I have two java classes at src/main/java folder as it should be and after many attempts to upload and tun the project I've also built a jar file and its location is at out/artifacts/1_jar/1.jar though this didn't help.
So what do I do?

In addition, to successfully build a project I had to put this 3 strings in the build.gradle as it was described [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-gradle-apps-on-heroku#example-applications)

```
ask stage(dependsOn: ['build', 'clean'])
build.mustRunAfter clean
heroku config:set GRADLE_TASK="build"
```

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, environment variables are used with the `$` notation. You'll need to create a second file called `Procfile.windows` with the contents:

```
web: java -Dserver.port=%PORT% %JAVA_OPTS% -jar build\libs\*.jar
```

Then run `heroku local web -f Procfile.windows`

But leave the `$` for Heroku, which uses Linux.

Comment: Your Procfile.windows says 'web: web:', but I think it should be just 'web:'.